# Tengo un "bug" al llamar al método de un type/interface en TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface, type

No se si sea problema del `tsconfig.json`, o del mismo TypeScript, pero cuando hago una interface/type que dentro tiene un método, y a ese método le pongo un parámetro obligatorio, después al llamarlo, si yo no pongo nada dentro de los paréntesis, en vez de marcarme error no me dice nada, lo cual es raro teniendo en cuenta lo estricto que es TypeScript. En la línea 4 se puede ver que le pasé el parámetro de `id: number`, y en la línea 8, por mas que no le pase ningún parámetro me lo acepta igual, la idea sería que me salte un error ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código acá lo dejo:

```
(()=>{

    interface Client {
        getClient(id: number): string
    }

    class ClientManagerment implements Client {
        getClient(){
            return "Client"
        }
    }

})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien es un comportamiento "algo extraño" no es relevante.

Se tiene:

```
interface Client {
    getClient(id: number): string
}
class ClientManagerment implements Client {
    getClient(): string{
        return "Client"
    }
}
```

**¿Qué estás diciendo en ese código?**

1. Que implementas la interfaz `Client`
2. Pero que no te interesa el argumento de la función `getClient` **en tu implementación**

Y que no te interese el argumento es una situación valida (y no tan poco común) en el uso de interfaces

**¿Por qué no es relevante?**

Porque la naturaleza da la interface es definir una estructura común a las clases que la implementan, y esto se cumple ya que si haces:

```
let myclient : Client = new ClientManagerment();
console.log(myclient.getClient(1000))
```

No hay ningún problema `getClient` va a recibir ese `1000` pero no lo va utilizar. Ahora probemos con una clase que si lo implemente

```
class ClientOtro implements Client {
    getClient(id: number): string{
        return "Client " + id;
    }
}
//let myclient : Client = new ClientManagerment();
let myclient : Client = new ClientOtro();
console.log(myclient.getClient(1000))
```

Si te fijas la instrucción `myclient.getClient(1000)` se utiliza igual, ya sea que `myclient` fuese del tipo `ClientManagerment` o `ClientOtro` y es justamente este el punto importante de usar interfaces, poder trabajar con tipos distintos como si fueran lo mismo

**¿Y cuándo importaría?**

Cuando se da el caso inverso, es decir en la interfaz no existe el argumento y tú la implementas con argumento (Esto no es posible de realizar)

```
interface Client {
    getClient(): string
}
class ClientManagerment implements Client {
    getClient(id: number): string{  // Aquí marca Error
        return "Client " + id;
    }
}
```

Y claro porque ahora `ClientManagerment` necesita de un argumento, pero el resto de la implementaciones de `Client` pueden no tenerlo, haciendo que la función `getClient` no sea común para todas la clases que implementan la interfaz.

Comment: no sabes si se puede realizar una sobrecarga de métodos en la misma clase? por ejemplo quiero que getClient tenga una versión con parámetros y una sin?

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego Tu pregunta es compleja, porque según la documentación si es posible, pero según mi opinión no lo es. Javascript no tiene sobrecarga y typescript está amarrado a él. Typescript tiene al menos 2 formas de "simular" la sobrecarga, una se usar el operador pipe `|` algo así: `getClient(id:void | number)` y la otra es solo declarar las funciones (sin la implementación) y luego crear un función "padre" lo más genérica posible.

Comment: En ambos casos debes implementar un código interior (unos `if`) que validen que tipo de datos está ingresando, por este motivo considero que no es una sobrecarga al 100%, es como un `switch` con vitaminas. Por lo cual yo (y a modo personal) prefiero no usarlos

Comment: Si, no es posible hacerlo realmente, es una sobrecarga maquillada lo del pipe y los ifs. Qué raro que no tenga esa característica porque lenguajes como Java la tienen.

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego A mí siempre me ha dado la impresión de que ha Typescript lo crearon como un Polyfill a ecma5 mientras se discutía ecma6, si te fijas en el código generado por TS es muy similar a ecma6 (salvo los tipo de datos). Por este motivo creo que decidieron no alejarse demasiado de lo que podía hacer javascript y javascript no tiene sobrecarga. Luego de la salida de ecma6 y gracias a los beneficios de un lenguaje fuertemente tipado ha hecho que TS no caiga al olvido (ayuda también que grandes framework lo implementaron)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que no es un bug a mi me pasa lo mismo, si usas implements Client en la clase no te va a tirar error si la funcion getClient() no tiene parametros, y solo ocurre con los parametros porque si devuelve algo que no sea un string si me tira error.

```
interface Client {
    getClient(id:string) :  string
}

class ClientManagerment implements Client{
  getClient(){
    return "Client"
  }

  // getClient(){  (!error no puede devolver number)
  //   return 123
  // }
}
```

Otra cosa ocurre si creas un objeto usando new de la siguiente forma y despues llamando al metodo sin pasarle parametros:

```
let myclient : Client = new ClientManagerment();
console.log(myclient.getClient()) // error: se esperaba 1 argumento, se obtuvieron 0
```

o pasandole un numero en lugar de un string:

```
console.log(myclient.getClient(123)) // No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "number" al parámetro de tipo "string"
```

Parece que el implements solo restringe los nombres de las propiedades y los valores devueltos mas no los parametros.